# I downloaded a package and all of its dependencies, how can I easily install them all at once?

Tags: apt, dpkg, deb

I downloaded .deb packages with their dependencies.

How could I install it once?
Like automically searches for its dependencies on my library.

Comment: If you really have all the correct packages and these packages are provided by a configured software source, you can put them in `/var/cache/apt/archives` as explained in [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/1016/22949). For this and other methods, see [How can I install software or packages without Internet (offline)?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/974/how-can-i-install-software-or-packages-without-internet-offline). If you believe that question doesn't apply or none of the solutions there are what you're looking for, please [edit] this question to explain more about your situation. Thanks!

Comment: I'm not really sure this is a duplicate. The answer might be the same, but I think the questions are different.

Answer (score 1):

> I downloaded .deb packages with their dependencies... How could I install it once?

You can use 1 installation instruction with the package names divided by a "space".

Example

```
 dpkg -i first.deb second.deb third.deb
```

You can also install all .DEBs in a directory with ...

```
dpkg -R --install packages/
```

If packages/ has first.deb second.deb third.deb it will install them all.

This will not "automically searches for its dependencies on my library...". It will install the packages listed; nothing more. It is you who needs to make sure the dependencies are all downloaded too.

---

There is a tool to help you with dpkg called "gdebi". Installation:

```
sudo apt-get install gdebi-core
```

You can install .deb packages like this ...

```
sudo gdebi /path/to/filename.deb
```

and it will also try to install dependencies.

---

And do not forget: when you get a broken package warning due to above: `sudo apt-get -f install` will fix most of those (if not all)

Comment: could I copy it to /var/cache/apt and install it using apt-get?

Comment: Yes but it can cause problems (mostly those pesky "broken packages" messages) if you have apt-get install something and you missed a package.

Answer (score 1):

If all deb's with dependencies are exist in one directory then you can install as below.

Open terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and change to directory (`cd <path/to/directry>`) containing all .deb's and install by following command:

```
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```